# How does runtime memory editing software works?

Tags: c++, memory, runtime

I tried to make two simple programs, one just prints a value stored in a memory address indefinitely, and the other one tries to change that value directly from that address. I don't know if it is useful, but here is the code.

```
// printing program
int main() {
    int *ptr { new int(255) };
    cout << ptr << '\n'; // to know the address for the second program
    while(true) cout << '\r' << *ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

-

```
// editing program, gets run after first program
int main() {
    int *ptr { (int*)0xabcdef }; // the address that the first one prints.
    *ptr = 256;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to change the value it gives me a `Segmentation fault` error(I may be wrong, as I'm not at home to confirm this), which says that the memory address is not accesible from the current process.

So my question is simple, how does a process is able to read and write values on memory addresses that do not belong to that process? From what I see, the first program does not need additional code for the editor one to work. A C++ example would be awesome, but I'm good with an explanation too.

Comment: On modern protected multi-tasking operating systems processes are *separated*. One process can not access memory from another process. Each process will have its own memory map. To access the memory of another process you have to use the operating system to be able to *share* the memory. Or in certain cases map the memory from another process into your own process (usually needs special privileges to bypass the memory protection).

Comment: The address in your pointer is not the actual location on a chip of RAM in your computer.  Instead, the address is routed through the MMU https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit to have the actual memory location be determined.   This mapping is different for each process.  Even if it weren't, though, you still wouldn't be allowed to access memory not owned by your process, so you'd still get an error.